# mvc paypal payment details amount dont show

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

In my project include paypal express check out. I send all details in below class. And My code below;

```
public class PayPal
{
    public static PayPalRedirect ExpressCheckout(PayPalOrder order)
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["USER"] = PayPalSettings.Username;
        values["PWD"] = PayPalSettings.Password;
        values["SIGNATURE"] = PayPalSettings.Signature;
        values["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
        values["VERSION"] = "63.0";
        values["RETURNURL"] = PayPalSettings.ReturnUrl;
        values["CANCELURL"] = PayPalSettings.CancelUrl;
        values["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "SALE";
        values["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "USD";
        values["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = order.Amount.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        values["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC"] = "Apart Name";


        values = Submit(values);

        string ack = values["ACK"].ToLower();

        if (ack == "success" || ack == "successwithwarning")
        {
            return new PayPalRedirect
            {
                Token = values["TOKEN"],
                Url = String.Format("https://{0}/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token={1}",
                   PayPalSettings.CgiDomain, values["TOKEN"])
            };
        }
        throw new Exception(values["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
    }

    private static NameValueCollection Submit(NameValueCollection values)
    {
        string data = String.Join("&", values.Cast<string>()
          .Select(key => String.Format("{0}={1}", key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values[key]))));

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
           String.Format("https://{0}/nvp", PayPalSettings.ApiDomain));

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
        }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

and my controller ;

```
 public ActionResult Pay(FormCollection form)
    {
        var redirect = PayPal.ExpressCheckout(new PayPalOrder { Amount = 50 });
        Session["token"] = redirect.Token;
        return new RedirectResult(redirect.Url);
    }
```

But I cant show amount on paypal page????? I show desc but I dont show amount??? what is wrong? thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you passing `Amount` or not, I think you are not passing `Amount` Value If not then add

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }

   public ActionResult Pay()
   {
      PayPalRedirect redirect = PayPal.ExpressCheckout(new PayPalOrder { Amount = 50 });

      Session["token"] = redirect.Token;

      return new RedirectResult(redirect.Url);
   }
}
```

For More Details Check [PayPal with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/paypal-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I added it. And Amount is in coming PayPalOrder But I cant see amount when sending on paypal page.

Comment: can My problem for version?

Comment: may be try to change the version and then check.

Comment: I check it. and change version 63.0. but it is not show. i cant understand what is wrong?

Comment: Yep I found :). Must be use L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_..... Just PAYMENTREQUEST_AMT dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing over a line item name and amount and see if it shows up in that case.  Also, can you provide the actual string of data you are sending over to PayPal, minus your API credentials so that I can test it with my API credentials.

Example:

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=paypal_api1.x.com&PWD=NAEWP67N2BMRSD234P2&SIGNATURE=Ae0iZ4smtdchhBLFKKdS8s8OSA220f033rNWM4EYTk1J-tsdbDOFq0JpNi&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=92.0&RETURNURL=https://www.ccaples.com/mts/pp_nvp_quick_test.php&CANCELURL=https://www.ccaples.com/mts/pp_nvp_quick_test.php&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=200&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=200&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test EC payment
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I try it. And Message ;

TIMESTAMP=2013%2d05%2d20T11%3a50%3a37Z&CORRELATIONID=c0bf84f7e61fb&ACK=Failure&VERSION=92%2e0&BUILD=6020375&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error....

My page message;

TOKEN=EC%2d09435481S1171634R&TIMESTAMP=2013%2d05%2d20T11%3a46%3a49Z&CORRELATIONID=f433f5dfdf68f&ACK=Success&VERSION=92%2e0&BUILD=6020375